# Get option present in the expanded notification in status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

i am able to get the text using bigtext in notification but few times when mail notification comes in the notification bar it has option when some link or google form or attachment is present. so is there any way to know that the incoming notification has option also attached with it .

Comment: May be not. You dont have permission to read other application notification.

Comment: i don't think so , because push bullet app actually does the same thing , they extract the entire notification from the notification drawer and then pass it to your desktop.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot i have found the way , incase you need the code you can dm me